# How to express desires in English so that they don't sound like commands?

Tags: phrases, expressions, offensive-language

> At that time I won't want you to again land up in the thread to tell me the rules.

With the above statement, I wanted to express my *desire*, but it was interpreted as a *command*.

How can I rewrite the same statement so that it doesn't sound like a command?

Comment: Your sentence is a little unclear. What do you mean by "land up"? That is not a common construction. Do you mean "end up"? Or "land"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are some softening tricks:

- *Won't* is a contraction for *will not,* which may sound authoritative.  *Wouldn't* can be softer than *won't*.
- In the subject of the sentence, use inclusive plural (*we, us*) rather than the second person (*you*), which can sound more like an accusation.
- Avoid embedding pronouns in a statement that make it sound more confrontational (like a *you* and a *me*).

After applying these three guidelines:

> I won't want you to land up in the thread again to tell me the rules.

becomes:

> I wouldn't want us to land up in the thread again, discussing the rules.

Of course, all of these tricks are contextual; they work well when in the midst of a disagreement.  I'm not saying to always avoid pronouns like *you* and *me* – yet I believe you're sharp enough to figure that out.

Comment: That is "beautiful". Very "beautiful". You have made the sentence too polite! I never prefer beating around the bush, perhaps that's why I couldn't think of the same. thanks.

Comment: Just a further suggestion - the phrasing "land up" sounds a little odd, and I can't help but suspect that what the OP is really after is "end up". Context is everything, though, and I can imagine situations in which "land up" would work. Nonetheless, I thought it worth at least mentioning: `I wouldn't want us to end up in the thread again, discussing the rules.`

Comment: @Anisha: As an aside, it's not really "beating around the bush," it's being aware of how certain words are interpreted when they are heard or read. My suggested change is no less direct, it's simply worded in a way that's less likely to arouse defense mechanisms, and sound confrontational.

Comment: J.R. Okay, now I understand. Not a native English speaker am I. I usually translate from Hindi to English. That may be the problem. You were too helpful, thanks.

Comment: @DaveMG Actually the person whom I was talking to is a moderator. So, I thought for a moderator, the "land up" phrase may make more sense? Is this wrong? :D

Comment: @AnishaKaul: The status of the person you are speaking to doesn't affect the choice between "land up" or "end up" *(strict accuracy: it's hard to imagine why it would, but we have to allow that in English anything is possible)*. The context is more important, and the only reasons I can think of (without knowing your specific situation) for using "land up" is if somehow the word or concept of "landing" was used earlier in the discourse. Otherwise, "end up" is the more natural phrase.

Comment: @DaveMG alright, I'll use end up in future. But the fact is that that moderator was not a part of the conversation in that thread. He "landed" there only to tell me the rules. :) :) That's why I thought of this term. I'll use "end up" in future.

Comment: It really depends on whether someone had at some point specifically described the moderator as having "landed" there, or if you are using the concept of "to land" for the first time in this example sentence. Anyway, there's only so far we can go without knowing the situation, so we won't drag this out. I just want to make sure you know that it's *not a rule* that "land up" is wrong and "end up" is right. It's more of a feel for what *sounds* right: "end up" is *probably* right, and "land up" *could work*, but only if the context supports it. Hope that helps! :)

Comment: @DaveMG Yes, it helps, and it would help more if you could give one example where "land up" will sound appropriate. :)

Comment: "It's difficult for a plane to land up in the mountains."

Comment: @DaveMG That's cheating. :) :) I was referring to the context of human landing - a kind of dry humor?

Comment: Is it really cheating? Both the concepts of the plane ending up in the mountains as well as landing (literally) are covered. It could be a response to "Did I just see a plane parked in the mountains?". In other words, someone says they say a plane, and the other person finds that hard to believe - how could a plane *end up* there? Landing there is difficult after all. If I said "It's difficult for a plane to end up in the mountains." It would mean almost the exact same thing. ;)

Comment: @DaveMG Alright, finally thanks for the pleasant conversation.

Comment: @Anisha: When dealing with human "landings," I think you'd use _land_ (no _up_), or _end up_, such as, "I don't want to land in the doghouse," or "I don't want to end up in the doghouse." ("in the doghouse" is an expression for being in trouble). "Land up" doesn't sound right, but I initially chose to put that aside in the early part of this discussion.

Comment: When I first read the quote, sans context, I read "up in" in the sense given by AAVE, meaning 'in, with a connotation of intrusion'; e.g., "He was getting up in my grill".

Answer (score 3):

There are many, many possible ways to express a desire politely in English.  Some examples follow.

- I'd really appreciate it if you could ...
- Would you be so kind as to ... ?
- It would be nice if you could ...
- Is there any chance you could ... ?
- If you could ..., it would be really good.

Don't be concerned that some of these sound like questions.  They're really not questions at all.

Comment: They may not be "real" questions, I feel that they are "polite requests". Even a polite request is not a desire. Your examples make me feel that I am *"asking"* him to do something. Whereas what I want is merely *"expressing my desire"* **without** asking him *"if he could fulfill my desires"*.

Comment: @AnishaKaul - I don't quite follow.  Are you saying you want to express your desire, but don't actually want to ask him to fulfil it?

Comment: I am saying that I want to express my desire, but don't actually want to ask him to fulfill it **OR not to fulfill it**. :)

Comment: @AnishaKaul So what is the purpose of expressing your desire, if not to manipulate this person into doing what you want?

Comment: I want to let him know what I want, and then I want to let him decide whether he thinks it is wise to fulfill or not (without any manipulations).

Comment: Where is the bowl of popcorn when you need one ? By the way what you two are doing is not productive, @AnishaKaul would you mind elaborating more so we can understand better what you want.

Comment: @AnishaKaul - I'm having difficulty understanding this, possibly because English is my first language, and we possibly don't have exactly what you're looking for in English.  If you were to tell me that you wanted something, I would automatically assume that it was a request, and thus feel obliged to EITHER do what you want, OR explain to you why I don't want to do what you want.  The concept of someone telling me what they want, then me just ignoring their desire, doesn't really fit within my world view; and possibly not within the world view of other native English speakers.

Comment: @speedyGonzales You said: `By the way what you are doing is not productive` I am trying to express what I feel. If you think that's not productive, "ignore me".

Comment: David, you said: `and we possibly don't have exactly what you're looking for in English` I do think the same. My original sentence was a direct translation from Hindi to English. BTW, it just striked me that is it a possibility that the sub statement *"to tell me the rules."* offensive sounding?

Comment: Some things have to be kept in personal- emotions, thoughts, naked pictures and ect. You should be professional and polite. Just say a swear in your mind and move on.

Comment: @AnishaKaul You asked whether "to tell me the rules" is offensive sounding.  It doesn't sound offensive by itself.  But in the context of the conversation that you're having with this person, it may be.  I can't really answer this question without knowing more of the context.

Answer (score 1):

“It is my ardent desire that you wouldn’t land up again in the thread to tell me the rules, but you are at liberty to choose your own method.”

Answer (score 0):

Well, I would use something like:

> Would you mind not landing up in the thread to tell me the rules again? I think we have already been here.

It has an authoritative polite tone.

It is the similar to:

> Would you mind not smoking?

Comment: Starting with "Would you mind" is a "question". I want to write a "statement", not a question.

Comment: I think it is more like request not question (see the new example) and your so called statement is in the second sentence - it express irritation. In conclusion you politely ask him to do something and express irritation of his desire to do it over and over again.

Comment: `your so called statement is in the second sentence - it express irritation.` Maybe, I just wanted to remove the irritation part of it. :)

Comment: If don't want to express irritation, how are you expecting him to understand that you don't like it ? Reading your mind ?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes beginning sentences with a positive attire sounds gentle and well non-offensive:

`I'd be delighted to have you land up in the thread again to tell me the rules except for that time.`